# Pick exact records

Tags: sql, oracle, join, duplicates, inner-join

```
INSERT INTO filerecord (fname,
                                  lname,
                                  transdate,
                                  memberid)
 VALUES ('tyler',
         'smith',
         TO_DATE ('07/01/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),
         '111');
```

I get the following result:

```
fname      lname              email
fernando    hernandez   fh@yahoo.com
fernando    hernandez   ts@hotmail.com
```

IT should not display Tyler Smith's Name & Email due to the transdate clause. I am looking for someone to get me only the Fernando Result. 
I cannot change the structure of the tables.

Comment: Share what output you are getting and what output you are aiming at.

Comment: I get the following result:
    fname      lname              email
    fernando hernandez fh@yahoo.com
    fernando hernandez ts@hotmail.com

Comment: Sure.  E.g., adding `AND b.fname = e.fname AND b.lname = e.lname`, for example to your query would fix it.  But you don't want to just write joins that work for your query... you want to write _correct_ joins.  That is, figure out what the `PRIMARY KEY` or other `UNIQUE KEY` is on each table and use one of them in your join.

Comment: Editing your question to  *Testing.....Nothing works. I am done trying!* isn't going to be well received.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. I just created a new table and checked.

**Table member**

```
create table member (programid varchar(10), memberid int, fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10), email varchar(25))
```

Content

```
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| PROGRAMID | MEMBERID |  FNAME   |   LNAME   |     EMAIL      |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
| BLUE      |      111 | tyler    | smith     | ts@hotmail.com |
| GREEN     |      111 | fernando | hernandez | fh@yahoo.com   |
+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

**Table filerecord**

```
create table filerecord (fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10), transdate date, memberid int);
```

Content

```
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
| FNAME | LNAME | TRANSDATE | MEMBERID |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
| tyler | smith | 7/1/2016  |      111 |
+-------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

**Last Query**

```
SELECT b.fname, b.lname, e.email
     FROM filerecord b, member e
     WHERE     b.memberid IN ('111')
     AND b.memberid = e.memberid
     AND b.transdate >= TO_DATE ('07/02/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

**Result -**

*no rows selected.*

Comment: where is fernando in the bouncedfundingfile record table?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a Cartesian product.

You have two entries with `memberid` = '111' in both tables, so this condition

```
 AND b.memberid = e.memberid
```

filters you down to 4 rows --

- one with Tyler Smith joined to Tyler Smith's email
- one with Fernando Hernandez joined to Fernando Hernandez's e-mail,
- one with Tyler Smith joined to Fernando Hernandez's email and
- one with Fernando Hernandez joined to Tyler Smith's email

Then, this condition:

```
AND b.transdate >= TO_DATE ('07/02/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

excludes two of those but not the other two.

You need a better data model and/or a more exact way to join your two tables.

In general, anytime you join two tables, one of the tables should have all of its primary key columns specified to avoid this type of error.  (There are exceptions to that, as always).

Comment: I know that too. I cant change the structure now as it has millions of records. I thought some genius out there can get me the correct email address record.

Comment: Can some logic be used within a procedure and get the correct output?

Answer (score 0):

Since `memberid` is not a unique identifier, there no reason to expect good things from a join condition like `b.memberid = e.memberid`.

Instead, you seem to suggest (or believe) that `(memberid, fname, lname)` should be a unique identifier. So, use it in the join condition:

```
... WHERE ...   AND b.memberid = e.memberid 
                AND b.fname    = e.fname 
                AND b.lname    = e.lname 
          ...
```

Like so:

```
SQL> SELECT b.fname, b.lname, e.email
  2       FROM filerecord b, member e
  3       WHERE     b.memberid IN ('111')
  4       AND b.memberid = e.memberid
  5       AND b.fname    = e.fname
  6       AND b.lname    = e.lname
  7       AND b.transdate >= TO_DATE ('07/02/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

FNAME                LNAME                EMAIL
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
fernando             hernandez            fh@yahoo.com

1 row selected.
```